# Integration and Differentiation of Proper Time

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

My question concerns the general relativity setting.

**Integration:** Proper time is defined by $$\tau = \int_P\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu}$$ but happens when $g_{\mu\nu}\neq 0$ for $\mu\neq \nu$ ? For example, our metric tensor may be $$1\cdot dx^1 dx^2 + 2\cdot dx^2 dx^3,$$ in which case it seems apparently ill-defined to write an expression such as $$\int_P \sqrt{1\cdot dx^1 dx^2 + 2\cdot dx^2 dx^3}~?$$

**Differentiation:** What does it mean to differentiate some quantity by proper time? For instance, what does the expression $\frac{dx}{d\tau}$ mean in general relativity, both qualitatively and quantitatively? My qualm largely arises from how this expression seems completely ill-defined compared to the integration-definition of proper time.

I'm nearing the end of my first general relativity course and these things still confuse me.

Comment: Why would it be ill-defined to write $\sqrt{\mathrm{d}x^1\mathrm{d}x^2}$? It is a perfectly fine expression. If you parametrize a worldline by the proper time along it, then you can differentiate quantities living on the worldline by that parameter.

Comment: perhaps i find it troublesome because I'm looking for a mathematically sound expression; if the quantity is seen as summing up an infinitesimal it seems alright, but if you see it as integration of differential form, then that expression is ill-defined.

Comment: If I can't get an interpretation in terms of differential form, I'd actually be happy enough to have a description that allows me to carry out a standard calculation involving such an expression.

Comment: if $P:[a,b] \to M$, then $\tau = \int_a^b \sqrt{\sum_{\mu,\nu}g_{\mu\nu}(P(\lambda)) \cdot \mathrm dx^\mu(\dot P(\lambda)) \cdot \mathrm dx^\nu(\dot P(\lambda))} \,\mathrm d\lambda$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression for the length of a path $\gamma : I = [a,b] \to \mathcal{M}$

$$ L[\gamma] = \int_\gamma \sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^\mu\mathrm{d}x^\nu}$$

is a mnemonic expression (by this I mean that it tells you how you would calculate it in all cases, but that it is not the "rigorous" meaning) for taking the length of the tangent vector at every point w.r.t. the metric induced on the tangent spaces, that is

$$ L[\gamma] = \int_I \sqrt{g(\dot{\gamma}(t),\dot{\gamma}(t))} \mathrm{d}t$$

which is just the integral of a scalar function.

After defining proper time at a point $\gamma(t)$ on $\gamma$ as $\tau(t) = L[\gamma\rvert_{[a,t]}]$ one may parametrize $\gamma$ by $\tau$ instead of $t$, and consequently differentiate quantities living on the worldline $\gamma$ w.r.t. $\tau$.